# longtable midrule after newpage

Tags: longtable

How do I get a midrule above the first row on the 2nd page?

Tried:

- just putting a 2nd midrule in, but then i have 2 rules on page 1.
- a \ between them but then there is a empty row on the 2nd page.

  ```
  \begin{center}
  \begin{longtable}{ |l|l| }



          \toprule
          Eigenschaft                & Erklärung                                          \\ \midrule\midrule
          Client Server Architektur  & Client und Server sind durch eine Schnittstelle    \\
                                     & voneinander getrennt. „speration of  concerns“     \\ \midrule
          Zustandslosigkeit          & Der Server speichert keine Daten im Bezug auf      \\
                                     & den Nutzer über mehrere Anfragen hinweg.           \\
                                     & D. h. jede Anfrage steht für sich allein und kann   \\
                                     & als eigene Transaktion gesehen werden.             \\ \midrule
          Pufferbarkeit              & Antworten des Servers müssen Informationen         \\
                                     & über die zu puffernde Dauer enthalten.            \\ \midrule
          Mehrschichtigkeit          & Der Server kann die Daten selbst liefern           \\
                                     & oder die Daten von einem  zweiten Server erhalten, \\
                                     & ohne dass der Client einen Unterschied feststellt. \\ \midrule
          Einheitliche Schnittstelle & Die Kommunikation zwischen Client und Server       \\
                                     & ist über ein  einheitliches Verfahren geregelt.    \\ \midrule
          Code bei Bedarf            & Der Server kann ausführbaren Code an den           \\
                                     & Client liefern.                                    \\ \bottomrule

      \caption[RESTful Service-Eigenschaften]{\ac{REST}ful Service-Eigenschaften\autocite[vgl.][S. 66 ff]{odata}}
  \end{longtable}
  \end{center}
  ```

[image: Probmlem as Picture]

Thanks for your help.

Eric

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please how your code, not images, (3) make the code fully complilable on its own (easier for others to  test), (4) this is explained in the longtable manual, as you don't show any code, we cannot see if you followed the instructions in the manual

Comment: @daleif thanks, do you have a template for minimal runnable code?

Comment: How did you run the code above? Which does not use the build in feature to add a rule after a page break.

Comment: i just put \usepackage{longtable} in my setting and added to code above to my content

Comment: We cannot see your preamble, your document class etc. Those my be important. Leaving it out means that others who wan to help have to make a preamble etc for your code in order to test your code. A preamble that might not match your use case. This makes it less likely that others are going to help. Again, read the `longtable` manual, if you do not know how to find the manual on your own system, see texdoc.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\midrule` is perfectly supported by  longtable, but you have to repect the particular syntax of `longtable`: the horizontal rules at the bottom and top of pages should be coded in the `\endfoot` and `\endhead` sections at the beginning of the code.

*Some observations*:  `booktabs` adds some vertical padding around its rules, so they do not intersect vertical rules, which are not recommended anyway. As a work-around, you can suppress this padding setting the values of `\aboverulesep` and  `\belowrulesep`  to 0pt  (within a group); or you canuse another package which provides table rules with customisable width, such as `boldline` or `makecell`.

Also, traditional typography places table caption *above* tables, not below, for a very simple reason: when a table spreads over several pages, the reader does not want to have to turn pages in order to know what this table is about. So normally, in a long table , the `\caption` command is placed in the `firsthead` section, not in the `lastfoot`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{longtable,array, booktabs, lipsum}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\doublespacing
\lipsum[8-9]
\bigskip

{\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|}
        \toprule
\endfirsthead
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
    \caption[RESTful Service-Eigenschaften]{\autocite{REST}ful Service-Eigenschaften\autocite[vgl.][S. 66 ff]{odata}}
\endlastfoot
        Eigenschaft & Erklärung \\ \midrule\midrule
        Client Server Architektur & Client und Server sind durch eine Schnittstelle \\
                                   & voneinander getrennt. „speration of concerns“ \\ \midrule
        Zustandslosigkeit & Der Server speichert keine Daten im Bezug auf \\
                                   & den Nutzer über mehrere Anfragen hinweg. \\
                                   & D. h. jede Anfrage steht für sich allein und kann \\
                                   & als eigene Transaktion gesehen werden. \\ \midrule
        Pufferbarkeit & Antworten des Servers müssen Informationen \\
                                   & über die zu puffernde Dauer enthalten. \\ \midrule
        Mehrschichtigkeit & Der Server kann die Daten selbst liefern \\
                                   & oder die Daten von einem zweiten Server erhalten, \\
                                   & ohne dass der Client einen Unterschied feststellt. \\ \midrule
        Einheitliche Schnittstelle & Die Kommunikation zwischen Client und Server \\
                                   & ist über ein einheitliches Verfahren geregelt. \\ \midrule
        Code bei Bedarf & Der Server kann ausführbaren Code an den \\
                                   & Client liefern.
\end{longtable}
}
        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \midrule doesnt seem to be supported in longtable in a manor that it draws 2 lines at page break. Instead I needed to use /hline.